# Should Patches have own branch in git workflow?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-strategy

I am reading [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow#) about git branching strategie. Where to assign patches? should patches have their own branch? If yes where should patches branched from? from master branch?

Answer (score 2):

If by "patches" you mean hotfixes to production, then yes, each one should be on its own branch named hotfix/xxx, where "xxx" is something that describes the hotfix. These branches should be branched off of master, and when ready should be merged into both master and develop.

Comment: Well patches and hotfixes are two things. in the git doc the hotfixes are explained in the workflow but not the patches. this is why i am asking here